# Scaling the size of equations

Tags: amsmath

How do I make the following set of equations look bigger?

The exponent in the exponential looks terribly small even when I use 'displaystyle' .

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[]{amsmath}
\usepackage[]{xcolor}
\usepackage[]{enumitem}
\usepackage[]{graphicx}
\allowdisplaybreaks

\title{something}
 \author{someone}
 \date{October 2016}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{something}

\begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*)]
\item

\begin{align*}
    \displaystyle{\langle x_{b}, t_{b}|x_{a}, t_{a}\rangle}
    &\displaystyle{= \int \mathcal{D}x\ \mathcal{D}p\ e^{iS/\hbar}}\\
    &\displaystyle{= \lim_{N\to\infty}\prod_{i=1}^{N}\bigg[\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx_{i}\bigg]\prod_{j=1}^{N+1}\bigg[\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{dp_{j}}{2\pi\hbar}\bigg]e^{iS_{N}/\hbar}}\\
    &\displaystyle{= \lim_{N\to\infty}\prod_{i=1}^{N}\bigg[\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx_{i}\bigg]\prod_{j=1}^{N+1}\bigg[\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{dp_{j}}{2\pi\hbar}\bigg]
      e^{\frac{i}{\hbar}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{N+1}[p_{k}(x_{k}-x_{k-1})-\epsilon H(p_{k},x_{k},t_{k})]}}.
\end{align*}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: you need to remove all the `\displaystyle` as they are doing nothing `align` is already display, and as it does not take an argument the `{...}` form a group and mess up the spacing, if you want it bigger you could put `\large` before the environment.

Comment: please always post complete documents no one can run that and see the problem and test answers without filling in all the missing parts, it is more helpful if they are there to start with.

Comment: Probably for legibility Zarko's "exp" notation is better, but if you really want to use a superscript you can put `\textstyle` or `\displaystyle` _inside_ the superscript to force it to the style of inline or displayed math. (Being inside a superscript, it is by default shown in `\scriptstyle`.)

Answer (score 3):

Superscripts and subscripts of math operators in superscript are really small. Therefore it is sensible to move math expression in the superscript in the last line to main line, i.e. replace `e^{...}` with `\exp(...)` which is actually intended for just such a case:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
    \begin{align*}
\langle x_{b}, t_{b}|x_{a}, t_{a}\rangle
    & = \int \mathcal{D}x\,\mathcal{D}p\,\mathrm{e}^{iS/\hbar}\\
    & = \lim_{N\to\infty}\prod_{i=1}^{N}\biggl[\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx_{i}\biggr]
            \prod_{j=1}^{N+1}\biggl[\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{dp_{j}}{2\pi\hbar}\biggr]
            \mathrm{e}^{iS_{N}/\hbar}\\
    & = \begin{multlined}[t][0.7\textwidth]
        \lim_{N\to\infty}\prod_{i=1}^{N}\biggl[\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx_{i}\biggr]
            \prod_{j=1}^{N+1}\biggl[\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{dp_{j}}{2\pi\hbar}\biggr]    \\
        \exp\biggl(\frac{i}{\hbar}\sum_{k=1}^{N+1}[p_{k}(x_{k}-x_{k-1})-\epsilon H(p_{k},x_{k},t_{k})]\biggr).
\end{multlined}
    \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1. A small point: if you replace `\bigg[` and `\bigg]` with `\biggl[` and `\biggr]`, respectively, you'll tighter (and, IMHO, better) spacing of the square brackets. Also, in the final row, consider replacing `\left(` and `\right)` with `\biggl(` and `\biggr)`, resp. The directive `\limits` after `\sum` isn't needed since display math is in effect. Finally, in the first integral expression, the amount of space inserted by "`\ `" seems excessive; a thinspace (`\`) seems more appropriate.

Comment: @Mico, in my edit of answer I consider (hopefully all) your suggestion. In the first answer version my intention
 was to show a possible solution of OP problem.

Comment: I've taken the liberty of replacing a few more `\bigg` directives -- those in row 3 -- with `\biggl` and `\biggr`, resp., and I've deleted `\limits`. Feel free to revert.